# How to open another website link in facebook webview in android studio its not working

Tags: webview

I have added the all permission for webview but its not open the link

> **Error** is Same site-none in Chrome cookies

Whats its mean

```
  web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

  web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

  web.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

  web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);


  web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
  web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
  web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
  web.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
  web.getSettings().supportZoom();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used in my kotlin project. It is not java, but hopefully you get the idea - you start view intent.

```
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
        return if (handleUrlClicks(url)) {
            true
        } else super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
        val url = request.url.toString()
        return if (handleUrlClicks(url)) {
            true
        } else super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
    }

}

private fun handleUrlClicks(url: String): Boolean {
    startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)))
    return true
}
```